# How to Change the styles of mat card which is used in Angular library component

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material2

I have used mat-card in angular library component like the below

```
<mat-card class="la-card">
  <mat-card-header class="la-card__header">
    <mat-card-subtitle>Field</mat-card-subtitle>
    <mat-card-title>Case title</mat-card-title>
  </mat-card-header>
  <mat-card-content class="la-card__content">
    <p>
      The Shiba Inu is the smallest of the six original and distinct spitz breeds of dog from Japan.
      A small.
    </p>
  </mat-card-content>
  <mat-card-actions class='la-card__actions'>
    <button mat-button>Created</button>
    <button mat-button>Details</button>
  </mat-card-actions>
```

and i gave the style like the below

```css
.la-card__header {
    margin: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;

    .mat-card-header-text {
      margin: 0;
    }
  }
```

The margin '0' is not applying to header text class .mat-card-header-text. How can i remove the margin to that classs. That class i can see when i inspect the mat-card component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the deep class selector when selecting your class `.mat-card-header-text`.

```
.<your-class> {
   .<parent-class> {
     .la-card__header {
       .mat-card-header-text {
         margin: 0;
       }
     }
   }
}
```

In this example, we are adding an extra class selector to beat the material CSS selector.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following css selector to reach deep angular classes `::ng-deep`.

CSS rule that resets margin in this case would be:

```
::ng-deep .mat-card-header-text {
  margin: 0;
}
```

And as for a full code snippet it would be:

```
.la-card__header {
  margin: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;

  ::ng-deep .mat-card-header-text {
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

Hope This helped.

Comment: I have read in some of SO links that ng-deep is deprecated? Any other recommended way?

Comment: It won't get deperecated, consider all the projects you worked on and used ::ng-deep in them, what would happen if browsers stopped supporting ::ng-deep?
Poeple talking about being ng-deep deprecated are usually referring to the usage related to the effect it causes outside the component (All .mat-card-header-text elements will have a margin of 0, even outside your component) BUT, the alternative is using :host before ::ng-deep, or exactly as you did by wrapping the rule with a class (The .la-card__header class).

Comment: In this way, only .mat-card-header-text classes that are wrapped with .la-card__header class will be affected.

Comment: Got It! Thank you @Mohamed.Karkotly